# EPDM roof edging trim

Tags: roof, waterproofing, shed

I've laid an EPDM roof on my shed/workshop, and I've now got to trim the edging, using wooden battens - what I'm not sure of is whether to put them on the edge, or underneath:

[image]

Most of the pictures I can see on the internet show them on the edge, as per the second picture, but wouldn't that invite water to get into the gap between the batten and the rubber, then wick through the screw holes holding the batten on? (which is exactly what happened with the old felt roof)

There's no fascia as such, and the pitch is around 15 degrees.

Comment: I have a EPDM roof that has lasted since 2004 that is configured like second picture (but with a metal piece rather than a wood batten). The upper seam where the batten meets the EPDM was caulked with silicone across entire length and all screws were caulked when driven.